# What is the difference between $Hom(V,V)$ and $End(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

I've learned that endomorphisms are structure preserving maps from a set to itself. But I thought that was what $Hom(V,V)$ was.

**What is the difference between $Hom(V,V)$ and $End(V)$?**

Comment: I don't believe there is a difference.

Comment: +1 there is no difference.  The first is the definition of the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An endomorphism is an homomorphism $\varphi:S \to T$ in which $S=T$. Therefore $\mathrm{Hom}(S,S)=\mathrm{End}(S)$.